# Array modifier offset

Tags: modifiers

[image]

I applied an array modifier to my object and for some reason I am getting an offset. I did see the other thread "Array modifier make unwanted offset", but that didn't answer my question. I don't know where the offset is coming from or how to correct it.

Comment: Maybe non uniform scale? Try selecting the object (in object mode) and pressing Ctrl+A (apply) and select "scale". There may be some rotation as well, it's hard to tell. If this is the case, select rotation & scale instead.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I had applied the scaled but not the rotation.